# When to use “grateful” and “thankful”?

Tags: vocabulary

"Grateful" and "thankful" are used interchangeably, but are there any differences? It seems that "grateful" is more common.

Comment: What research have you done? For example, have you looked in a dictionary?

Comment: See [*these usage notes on **grateful / thankful***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/grateful-or-thankful) from Cambridge Dictionary. Mostly they're "equivalent / interchangeable", but somewhat counter-intuitively, ***thankful*** is more likely in contexts where there's no-one (except perhaps Fate or God) to explicitly express ***thanks*** to (so you're *thankful* something bad didn't happen, rather than *grateful*). Plus obviously it's always ***Thankfully** it didn't rain on the day of the picnic* - ***gratefully*** can't be used at all in that context.

Comment: I tried looking,but as I have said,they are interchangeable

Comment: If you don't explain your confusion and if you don't supply or say what type of research you did, the question will be closed.

Comment: Mari-Lou A,I checked the Cambridge dictionary and the free dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the two terms are mostly interchangeable in their use. Like many "pairs" of words in English that are mostly interchangeable, the terms "grateful" and "thankful" differing linguistic roots, namely Latin and German, respectively. Originally (that is, the better part of a thousand years ago), both words had much the same meaning.

Both are related to the concept of gratitude, which dictionaries have defined as "pleasing, readiness to show appreciation for and to return kindness". I would describe it as the emotion/feeling associated with receiving kindness, aid or benefit. I would best describe it as "happiness", but often with feelings of indebtedness, as well.

Today, they can still be used interchangeably, but they tend to be used in slightly different contexts.

"Grateful" is mostly used to express gratitude directly towards *a person (or persons)* for their action or choice. Confusingly, such gratitude is also expressed with the expression "(I) thank you", though "I" is usually implied and omitted, except in rather formal and/or archaic speech.

"Thankful" is also used to express gratitude, but generally about *a situation*, rather than a person.

This is clearer if one looks at the usages of their adverbial forms ("gratefully and "thankfully"). "Gratefully" usually modifies active verbs, and describes the performance of actions in a matter that express their gratitude. "Thankfully" usually modifies passive verbs that describe a situation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!That is pretty much comparable to other dictionaries..